# need some help swaping two column values in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a rather large table in mysql and I need to do a mass update to switch 2 column values

- table_x

  - column_1
  - column_2

I need to move all of the values over from 'column_1' to 'column_2' and the values from 'column_2' to 'column_1'

Any ideas how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it just a matter of the column names? If so, you could just make an ALTER TABLE to swap the names and you are done.

Comment: Will this work if there are Foreign Key constraints involving these columns?

Comment: no idea why I didn't think of that.. I just renamed the column names.. thanks!

Comment: @ypercube Rows should still be the same, so as long as you can swap the names those Foreign keys will still represent the same row. You would just have to update your querys for their columns have changed.

Comment: I cannot understand what you are saying. Foreign keys do not represent rows.